# Keras ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer conv2d_1: expected ndim=4, found ndim=5

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, keras, conv-neural-network

I have checked all the solutions, but still, I am facing the same error. My training images shape is `(26721, 32, 32, 1)`, which I believe it is 4 dimension, but I don't know why error shows it is 5 dimension.

```
 model = Sequential()

 model.add(Convolution2D(16, 5, 5, border_mode='same', input_shape= input_shape ))
```

So this is how I am defining `model.fit_generator`

```
model.fit_generator(train_dataset, train_labels, nb_epoch=epochs, verbose=1,validation_data=(valid_dataset, valid_labels), nb_val_samples=valid_dataset.shape[0],callbacks=model_callbacks)
```

Answer (score 70, accepted):

The problem is `input_shape`.

It should actually contain 3 dimensions only. And internally keras will add the batch dimension making it 4.

Since you probably used `input_shape` with 4 dimensions (batch included), keras is adding the 5th.

You should use `input_shape=(32,32,1)`.

Comment: No, that number is free. Keras will show that dimension as `None` in the `model.summry()`, for instance.

Comment: My dimension for training data is array: `(26721, 32, 32)` and for valid. dimension is `(6680,32,32)`. Now I explicitly define image size (32,32,1) , then it gives me error `ValueError: Error when checking input: expected conv2d_9_input to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (6680, 32, 32)`  . I have also edit model_fit.generator in post, could you please check there?

Comment: Now the problem is in your data. Your data lacks the `channel` dimension: `x_validation = x_validation.reshape(6680,32,32,1)`

Comment: Thanks very much for your help

Comment: Can you help us here @DanielMöller. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64612084/valueerror-input-0-of-layer-sequential-157-is-incompatible-with-the-layer-expe

Comment: @DanielMöller I need an input shape of ndim=5, But my input shape= (18, 64, 1688), so I reshaped it as: data=data.reshape(18, 64, 1688, 1, 1). And pass this to my model that contains conv2D and convLSTM2D layers. But it gives me an error:     Input 0 of layer conv_lst_m2d_88 is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=5, found ndim=6. Full shape received: (None, None, 64, 211, 1, 128). How do I resolve it, kindly guide me, it will be a great favor.

Answer (score 9):

The problem is with `input_shape`. Try adding an extra dimension/channel for letting keras know that you are working on a grayscale image ie -->`1`

`input_shape= (56,56,1)`.
Probably if you are using a normal Deep learning model then it won't raise an issue but for Convnet it does.

Answer (score 7):

For reshape the data we need to add fourth dimensions i.e changing from `(6000,28,28)` to `(6000,28,28,1)`

My code is:

```
img_rows=x_train[0].shape[0]
img_cols=x_test[0].shape[1]

X_train=x_train.reshape(x_train.shape[0],img_rows,img_cols,1)

X_test=x_test.reshape(x_test.shape[0],img_rows,img_cols,1)


Input_shape=(img_rows,img_cols,**).  *->  I forgot to put 1 here.
```

I have face the same problem

`Input 0 is incompatible with layer conv2d_4 : except ndim=4 ,found ndim=3`

I solved this  problem by simply putting value in the input shape

```
Input_shape=(img_rows,img_cols,1)#store the shape of single image.
```

With this  problem is solved

Answer (score 3):

you can use :

train_dataset= train_dataset.reshape(-1,32,32,1)

and now you can use input_shape(32,32,1) in the algorithm.

Comment: Rather than just posting short comments `you could do this and then this` as an answer, you should illustrate how this can be achieved by for example showing the code implemented in the question. As it is now, this is a comment not an answer. Consider editing your answer to give more details.

Comment: @Sanketsz   I need an input shape of ndim=5, But my input shape= (18, 64, 1688), so I reshaped it as: data=data.reshape(18, 64, 1688, 1, 1). And pass this to my model that contains conv2D and convLSTM2D layers. But it gives me an error: Input 0 of layer conv_lst_m2d_88 is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=5, found ndim=6. Full shape received: (None, None, 64, 211, 1, 128). How do I resolve it, kindly guide me, it will be a great favor.

Answer (score 1):

I have faced the same problem

> Input 0 is incompatible with layer conv2d_4 : except ndim=4 ,found ndim=3

I solved this problem by simply putting value in the input shape

```
Input_shape=(img_rows,img_cols,1)#store the shape of single image. .. & the problem is solved
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you need to check the **"channels_first"** whenever CNN is used as 2d,Also reshape your train_data and test data as:

```
if K.image_data_format() == 'channels_first':   #check for channels_first
 train_img.reshape(train_img.shape[0],1,x,x)
 Input_shape=(1,x,x)                            #In your case x is 32
else:
 train_img.reshape(train_img.shape[0],x,x,1)
 Input_shape=(x,x,1)
```