# ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer conv2d_1: expected ndim=4, found ndim=5

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, keras-rl

I am trying to pass a RGB image from a simulator into my custom neural network. At the source of the RGB generation (simulator), the dimension of RGB image is `(3,144,256)`.

This is how I construct the neural network:

```
rgb_model = Sequential()
rgb = env.shape() // this is (3, 144, 256)
rgb_shape = (1,) + rgb
rgb_model.add(Conv2D(96, (11, 11), strides=(3, 3), padding='valid', activation='relu', input_shape=rgb_shape, data_format = "channels_first"))
Now, my rbg_shape is (1, 3, 144, 256).
```

This is the error I get:

```
rgb_model.add(Conv2D(96, (11, 11), strides=(3, 3), padding='valid', activation='relu', input_shape=rgb_kshape, data_format = "channels_first"))
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/sequential.py", line 166, in add
layer(x)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 414, in call
self.assert_input_compatibility(inputs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 311, in assert_input_compatibility
str(K.ndim(x)))
ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer conv2d_1: expected ndim=4, found ndim=5
```

Why is keras complaining that the expected dimension is 5 when my actual dimension is 4?

P.S: I have the same question as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47665391/keras-valueerror-input-0-is-incompatible-with-layer-conv2d-1-expected-ndim-4) question. I ideally wanted to comment on that post but don't have enough reputation.

**Edit:**

Here is the code that deals with the error:

```
rgb_shape = env.rgb.shape
rgb_model = Sequential()
rgb_model.add(Conv2D(96, (11, 11), strides=(3, 3), padding='valid', activation='relu', input_shape=rgb_shape, data_format = "channels_first"))
rgb_model.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3), strides=(2, 2), padding='valid', activation='relu', data_format = "channels_first" ))
rgb_model.add(Conv2D(384, (3, 3), strides=(1, 1), padding='valid', activation='relu', data_format = "channels_first"))
rgb_model.add(Conv2D(384, (3, 3), strides=(1,1), padding='valid', activation='relu', data_format = "channels_first"))
rgb_model.add(Conv2D(256, (3,3), strides=(1,1), padding='valid', activation='relu', data_format = "channels_first"))
rgb_model.add(Flatten())
rgb_input = Input(shape=rgb_shape)
rgb = rgb_model(rgb_input)
```

This is the new error when I pass `env.rgb.shape` as `input_shape` in `Conv2D`:

```
dqn.fit(env, callbacks=callbacks, nb_steps=250000, visualize=False, verbose=0, log_interval=100)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rl/core.py", line 169, in fit
    action = self.forward(observation)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rl/agents/dqn.py", line 228, in forward
    q_values = self.compute_q_values(state)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rl/agents/dqn.py", line 69, in compute_q_values
    q_values = self.compute_batch_q_values([state]).flatten()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rl/agents/dqn.py", line 64, in compute_batch_q_values
    q_values = self.model.predict_on_batch(batch)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1276, in predict_on_batch
    x, _, _ = self._standardize_user_data(x)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 754, in _standardize_user_data
    exception_prefix='input')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training_utils.py", line 126, in standardize_input_data
    'with shape ' + str(data_shape))
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected input_1 to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (1, 1, 3, 144, 256)
```

Answer (score 1):

The input shape of a Conv2D layer is `(num_channels, width, height)`. So you should not add another dimension (actually the input shape is `(batch_size, num_channels, width, height)` but you don't need to set `batch_size` here; it will be set in `fit` method). Just pass `input_shape=env.shape` to `Conv2D` and it would work fine.

**Edit:**

Why do you define an `Input` layer and pass it to the model? That's not how it works. First, you need to compile the model using `compile` method, then train it on the training data using `fit` method and then use `predict` method to make predictions. I highly recommend to read the [official guide](https://keras.io/getting-started/sequential-model-guide/) to find out how these things work.

Comment: Irrespective of I set the batch_size or not, I get the same type of error. When i pass the "env.shape" as is, i get a similar error
"ValueError : Error when checking input: expected input_1 to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (1,1,3,144,256)"

However, this time the error is coming from Keras-RL.

Comment: @user10193823 That's not the same error. It concerns the `Input` layer as mentioned in the error. You have inconsistent shapes. You should post the complete code.

Comment: @today- The reason why I do it is that I have multiple inputs and one of the input is an RGB image. The other includes other measurement vectors. I use Model where  I pass rgb_input along with other measurements. 
I followed the example that is posted on this link for my use case:
https://gist.github.com/bklebel/913d8f155e6ed23f8a35fba989c70140